# Why I'm led to an another email account in my IPhone 6 Plus(IOS 8.4)?

Tags: email, iphone

There are three email accounts on my phone. A standard account(gmail) and two additional accounts.

When clicking on the email icon on the bottom bar my phone opens sometimes my standard account and sometimes another account. It seems that it does not matter what account is the standard account because my phone opens any account randomly. Is there a way I can make my phone open my standard account or make my phone open the list view of all accounts but not a non-standard account.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely it opens the last one you looked at. On mine you then page back to the main page that lists all accounts and main mailboxes. Also what is a non standard account? gmail is not a standard account for me (it is one of the ones I use infrequently) :)

Comment: You are right but i want my phone open my standard account that i adjusted in the settings, there is an options to set one of my account as standard. Is there no way to open the standard but not the last account you looked at? Even after stopping the email app by double clicking on home button and drag it upwards it does not open my standard account :(

Comment: You mean your default account? That setting is used to define which account will be used by the system when sending mail from other apps, not to establish which account will present itself when you open Mail on iOS, I'm afraid.